# How to I convert from Type.FullName to a C# type name?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

Examples,

1. "Namespace.ClassName+NestedClassName" becomes "Namespace.ClassName.NestedClassName".
2. "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" becomes "System.Collections.Generic.List".

I need this for a code generator and I don't want to do a simple RegEx replace because of edge cases such as type names with '+' symbols in them. (Yes, though stupid that is possible.)

Comment: As far as I'm aware a `+` in a type name is illegal even at the CIL level. Can you show an example of a type with `+`?

Comment: Are you looking for code to do what you're asking?  As far as I know the plus just means it's a  nested private type

Comment: The documentation mentions the possibility and the escape sequence to use when it happens. "If the namespace contained a plus sign, for example TopNamespace.Sub+Namespace, then the plus sign (+) would be preceded by an escape character (\) to prevent it from being interpreted as a nesting separator." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Nested public types also use the plus symbol.

Comment: I'm hoping for a library that already does it, as I don't want to maintain my own parser.

Comment: I confirmed that you can define classes with a + in the name using CIL code. This is not supported in C#, VB, or F#, which means that we'll probably never see one in the wild unless it is created by a code generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the fully quantified name in C# format.
    /// </summary>
    public string CSharpFullName
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_CSharpFullName == null)
            {

                var result = new StringBuilder(m_TypeInfo.ToString().Length);
                BuildCSharpFullName(m_TypeInfo.AsType(), null, result);

                m_CSharpFullName = result.ToString();
            }
            return m_CSharpFullName;
        }
    }

    static void BuildCSharpFullName(Type typeInfo, List<Type> typeArgs, StringBuilder result)
    {
        var localTypeParamCount = typeInfo.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeParameters.Length;
        var localTypeArgCount = typeInfo.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments.Length;

        var typeParamCount = Math.Max(localTypeParamCount, localTypeArgCount);

        if (typeArgs == null)
            typeArgs = new List<Type>(typeInfo.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments);


        if (typeInfo.IsNested)
        {
            BuildCSharpFullName(typeInfo.DeclaringType, typeArgs, result);
        }
        else
        {
            result.Append(typeInfo.Namespace);
        }

        result.Append(".");
        foreach (var c in typeInfo.Name)
        {
            if (c == '`') //we found a generic
                break;
            result.Append(c);
        }

        if (localTypeParamCount > 0)
        {
            result.Append("<");

            for (int i = 0; i < localTypeParamCount; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                    result.Append(",");
                BuildCSharpFullName(typeArgs[i], null, result); //note that we are "eating" the typeArgs that we passed to us from the nested type.
            }
            typeArgs.RemoveRange(0, localTypeParamCount); //remove the used args


            result.Append(">");
        }
        else if (localTypeArgCount > 0 && typeArgs.Count > 0)
        {
            result.Append("<");

            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(localTypeArgCount, typeArgs.Count); i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                    result.Append(",");
                BuildCSharpFullName(typeArgs[i], null, result);
            }
            result.Append(">");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Type.GetType` to parse the string into a Type object.  From there you could use `GetGenericArguments` and other members to get the Type info of the individual components.  You could use those to reconstruct your target string.

Comment: You would still have to parse out "List\`1" from `Type.Name`. And perhaps I'm mistaken, but I don't see a way to get the parent type when `Type.IsNested = true`.

Comment: Apparently the parent type is in the DeclaringType property.